# Wordpress - Display single CPT from another WP database

Tags: php, wordpress

I have 2 WP sites with a job board (CPT created in functions.php alongside with archive-jobboard.php and single-jobboard.php):

- Parent site: all job posts are entered here and displayed on the front end
- Child site :I want jobs with specific term to be displayed on the front end.

What I have done so far:
- tried and succeed to retreive posts from parent site into child site with specific connnection database and query :

```
<?php global $wpdb; 
$wpdb_backup = $wpdb;
$wpdb = connect_to_site_DB();

$sitenews = new WP_Query(array(
'post_type' => 'jobboard',
'tax_query' =>(array('taxonomy'=> 'entreprise','field' => 'slug',terms =>'the_company_name')),
'post_status' => 'publish',
'orderby' => 'menu_order',
'order' => 'ASC',
'no_found_rows' => true,
'update_post_term_cache' => false, 
'update_post_meta_cache' => false, 
'ignore_sticky_posts' => true,
'nopaging' => true,
'posts_per_page' => 5,
));

if(!empty($sitenews->posts)) {
$counter_posts = 1;
    foreach ($sitenews->posts as &$post) 

        the_title( '<h2 class="entry-title"><a href="' . esc_url( get_permalink() ) . '" rel="bookmark">', '</a></h2>' ); 
    $counter_posts++;
}

$wpdb = $wpdb_backup; ?>
```

Now I want to display single posts. On click on the link in the archive page, I get a 404.

Is it even possible to display single posts from another WP?

Thank you

Comment: you can get them through the rest api

Comment: I tried but I blocked at the same point. I can display archive page (list of all my article) but can't display single post page.